# how to make model with pojo in android studio

Tags: android, model

Im trying to change from Gson format plugin to pojo.

im used to copy past the response into the gson format and it create whole model for me.

can I do the same with pojo? and if so how pls

Comment: Hi, please provide code that you already have that we can help you with the current issue. If I understand correctly and you want to work with server responses as pojo objects than you can write your own serializers for each pojo.

Comment: im not talking about specific response I want to know if its possible to copy past the response and the plugin create the model for me like gson format plugin and sorry for late answer

Comment: There are web sites that will do this. I don't think Android studio will.